# Getting NullPointerException trying to access "response" in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, web

In a JSP page, when the user logs out, I'm deleting their login cookies using this code:

```
Cookie killMyCookie = new Cookie("cookie1", null);
killMyCookie.setMaxAge(0);
killMyCookie.setPath("/JSPLearn");
response.addCookie(killMyCookie);
killMyCookie = new Cookie("cookie2", null);
killMyCookie.setMaxAge(0);
killMyCookie.setPath("/JSPLearn");
response.addCookie(killMyCookie);
```

After this, I'm calling

```
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

It's throwing a NullPointerException.

Why would response be null?

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:175)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at  com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: I don't know about JSP, but in the .NET world, if you set a cookie and then immediately redirect, the cookies don't actually get set, because the cookies need to be sent as part of the response, and redirecting hijacks that response.

Comment: could you post your whole stacktrace?

Comment: @cd6: It looks like the error is actually occurring in the source code of the page you redirect to `index.jsp`, on line 175

Answer (score 1):

check your index.jsp file I think you have a requet.getParameter(""); for a variable and when you use redirect you should send a value for that variable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies at

```
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:175)
```

I think you are trying something like `URLEncoder.encode` and first argument which is string to be encoded is Null and it is throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException`

It should be something like

`URLEncoder.encode("Hello World", "UTF-8");`